# Save date in given timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, react-datepicker

I'm using `react-datePicker` library which takes `new Date()` as input.
Here I'm taking input date, time & timezone. How I can save this in the backend such that if the user selects the date `Feb 10 2024` & time 02:00 & timezone BST irrespective of the location user should see the date as `Feb 10 2024 02:00 BST` in Date Object?

Right now `new Date("2024-02-10T03:00:00.000Z")` is giving me `Sat Feb 10 2024 08:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`. I want this should be `Sat Feb 10 2024 08:30:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time).
I already tried:

```
const tzname = "Europe/London";
const longOffsetFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {timeZone: tzname ,timeZoneName: "longOffset"});
const longOffsetString = longOffsetFormatter.format(new Date("2024-02-10T03:00:00.000"));
```

Moment.js could be helpful but it is legacy so not advised to use.

How I can save the Date based on the passed timezone instead local timezone?

Comment: FYI - `new Date(...anything...)` gives you a `Date` object - not any string at all.  You might see a string _representation_ if you log it, but that's not the object you created.  The `Date` object itself doesn't contain any time zone, or format.  It's just an object wrapper around a numeric UTC-based timestamp.  There's also no spec for consistency of logging `Date` objects, so you're better off calling `.toString()` or `.toISOString()` or some other function yourself, and logging that instead.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I did that and output was `Sat Feb 10 2024 08:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`. Can I update the timeZone for local browser?

Comment: If you want a fixed date, time and timezone (or offset?) then don't use a Date object, use a timestamp string like Feb 10 2024 02:00 GMT+01:00 (BST) or use a proper ISO 8601 format: 2024-02-10T02:00+01:00. Other minds have been working on these issues for over a century, you might leverage their knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `luxon` which provide modern alternatives to Moment.js and offer support for timezones.

```
const { DateTime } = require('luxon');

// User input values
const selectedDate = '2024-02-10'; // Example date
const selectedTime = '02:00'; // Example time

// Combine date and time into a single string
const dateTimeString = `${selectedDate}T${selectedTime}:00.000`;

// Create a DateTime object with the user-selected values in UTC
const utcDateTime = DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeString);

// Convert the UTC DateTime object to the local timezone
const localDateTime = utcDateTime.setZone('local');

// Format the local DateTime object in the desired format
const output = localDateTime.toLocaleString({
  weekday: 'short',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: '2-digit',
});

console.log(output);
```

The output is now

```
Sat, February 10, 2024, 2:00 AM // Or
Feb 10 2024 02:00 BST
```

Comment: FYI, you can just use `.setZone('local')` or `.toLocal()`